# Intercepting exit

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing unit tests for bash script and want to check if script quits on error (I use `exit` with errorcode).

Is there any way to catch `exit` (I know about `trap`), but don't interrupt command flow (something like exception catching)?

My test script:

```
do_smth1 && echo OK || echo Fail
do_smth2 && echo OK || echo Fail
do_smth3 && echo OK || echo Fail
```

my main script:

```
do_smth1(){
   ...
   ...
   [ $? -eq 0 ] && success || error_exit
}
```

and so on.

I'd like to execute all tests one after another. Now flow interrupts after first command.

Comment: Why can't you just check the return values? Do you run your test scripts with `set -e` and don't properly take care of return values of the script under test? Maybe you could expand your question with an example what (code) you have and what functionality you like instead.

Comment: What you show should work. Do you have `set -e` in effect by chance? What happens if you put `set +e` near the start of your test script?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes.

Comment: You probably should use `return` followed by an error code instead of `exit`. `return` will give the error code, but won't stop the process. If what you want is to return the exit status of the last command, just finish with that command.

Comment: Maybe a subshell? `( do_smth1 ) && echo OK || echo Fail`

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
success=0
error_code=1
do_smth1(){          
   ...          
   ...          
   [ $? -eq 0 ] && return $success || return $error_code         
}

do_smth1 && echo OK || echo Fail             
do_smth2 && echo OK || echo Fail             
do_smth3 && echo OK || echo Fail
```

Refer the man pages for exit and return, to know when to use which.